# Onde colocar ; neste código

Tags: php

```
        <p><b>Alvará: </b></p>
     <p>Numero: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;        Validade:   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;        Anexo:</p>';
    Echo' <p>'.$exibe["AlvaraNumero"].' 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ' 
        if ($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) { 
                                        if   (strtotime($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) < time()) 
                                        {
            echo '<span style="color:red">'.$exibe['AlvaraValidade'].'</span>';
            } else {
            echo $exibe['AlvaraValidade'];
            }
            } else { 
            echo 'N/D';
            }
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ' 
            echo '<a href="MostrarAlvara.php?id=' . $exibe['id'] . '">Ver PDF </a></p>
```

Estou a ter um erro  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting ',' or ';' in 
Neste pedaço de código:

```
     Echo' <p>'.$exibe["AlvaraNumero"].' 
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ' 
        if ($exibe['AlvaraValidade']) {
```

Comment: O seu código está estranho. Usar espaços em branco dessa maneira costuma ser sinal de algo que está a ser feito da maneira errada. De qq maneira, antes do seu primeiro `if`, falta o ponto e virgula `;`.

Comment: Eu estou a fazer isso porque não consigo colocar tabelas dentro de tab's por isso estou a experimentar o espaço em branco

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque é sobre um erro tipográfico de pouco ou nenhum valor para futuros visitantes.

Comment: @brasofilo Compreendo seu comentário sobre esse post, e sei que para manter a qualidade, esse tipo de coisa não deve ocorrer. Porém há pessoas que realmente estão iniciando agora! Ao invés de simplesmente encerrar a pergunta e deixar o cara sem a "resposta" do que seja, ajude-o como fiz logo abaixo. Realmente a pergunta dele não pode ajudar ninguém, mas uma resposta onde você irá "corrigindo" o código dele, acho que é sempre bem vindo e sempre bem visto por iniciantes na programação...

Comment: @DouglasBernardino, o site é para [*programadores profissionais e entusiastas*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). E não, não tem problema nenhum ajudar iniciantes com erros elementares. Mas também é bom sinalizar aos visitantes futuros (público alvo do site) que este tipo de pergunta não pertence ao escopo do site. Se a pergunta é fechada e você ainda quer ajudar, é só postar um comentário resumindo a solução. . . . . . Enfim, se quiser extender o debate, abra uma pergunta no [meta] ;)

Comment: @brasofilo não não, está tudo entendido :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cara, eu lhe aconselho em ao invés de colocar esse monte de "&nbsp" para fazer o espaçamento entre as palavras, use css em um span para definir esse espaçamento Ex:

css:

```
span{
 margin-left: 50px;
}
```

código de visualização:

```
Numero <span> Validade </span> <span> Anexo </span>
```

Claro, isso é só para exemplificar. Isso é bom visualmente e futuramente você vai se perder menos, e terá tudo mais organizado tendo isso como costume.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui...

```
'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  '
```

faça

```
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  ';
```